Azure DevOps Pipelines: Result shows green but step is partially succeeded
In Azure we have a pipeline with a deployment, a smoke test and two test steps. But when the first test fails and the second test is green, the overall result is still green.
The two last steps run parallel.
Is there any way, when one step fails or partially succeeds, the overall result shows the worst result in the pipeline?
We are using the classic pipelines.
Pipeline stages:


I can reproduce the same issue. Based on my investigation, the status of release will always reference the status of the last stage listed on the web UI as your screenshot shows (Cypress stage in your screenshot), regardless of whether the Cypress stage runs after or before other stages.
This looks like a defect of the releases. You can consider rising a ticket on Developer Community to report this issue to the Microsoft engineers.

As a workaround, you can try like as below:

Add a new stage (e.g., Detection) to depends on the Cypress stage. And enable "Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed" option on the new stage.


On Detection stage, add an agent job to run a PowerShell task.

Enable "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" on the agent job.


Set the environment variable "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN = $(System.AccessToken)" on the PowerShell task.


Run the following Inline script on the PowerShell task. Replace {organization-name} with the actual name of your Azure DevOps organization.
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization-name}/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=7.1"
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

$DetectFailed = $release.environments | Where-Object { $_.status -eq "rejected" }
$DetectPartiallySucceeded = $release.environments | Where-Object { $_.status -eq "partiallySucceeded" }

if ($DetectFailed.count -ge 1 )
{
    Write-Host "Failed"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
}
elseif ($DetectPartiallySucceeded.count -ge 1 )
{
    Write-Host "PartiallySucceeded"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=SucceededWithIssues;]PartiallySucceeded"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Succeeded"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Succeeded"
}





When above configuration:

The Detection stage will be listed as the last one on the web UI.

When Cypress stage is Failed, Detection stage gets skipped. The status of release will reference the status of Cypress stage which is listed before Detection on the web UI.

When Cypress stage is Succeeded or PartiallySucceeded, Detection stage runs. The status of release will reference the status of Detection stage.

The PowerShell script will call the REST API "Releases - Get Release" to get the list of all stages in current running release. It will check if any stage is rejected (Failed) status or partiallySucceeded status. If have failed stage, log the Detection stage as Failed using the logging command Complete. If no failed stage but partiallySucceeded stage, log the stage PartiallySucceeded (PartiallySucceeded). Otherwise, log the stage as Succeeded.




Does the workaround work for you? @SimonDamminga

Thanks for the answer. We had to change some things for our use case, but generally this is what we needed.
